# How to join two tables? - Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

### Users Model File

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
    "access_role_id":DataTypes.INTEGER,
    "user_type":{
      type:   DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['A', 'V', 'U']
    },
    "login_access":{
      type:   DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['APP', 'WEB', 'BOTH']
    },
    "username": DataTypes.STRING,
    "email": DataTypes.STRING,

    "updated_at":DataTypes.DATE,
    "created_at":DataTypes.DATE,
  }, {
    "timestamps": false,
    "createdAt": false,
    'updatedAt': false,
    "underscored": true,
    "freezeTableName": false,
  });
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    models.user.belongsTo(models.product, {targetKey: 'id',foreignKey: 'created_by'});
  };
  return user;
};
```

### User Controller File

```
const dbConfig = require( '../../../db/models/index');
let users =require('../../../db/models/user')(dbConfig.sequelizeDB,dbConfig.Sequelize);
module.exports = {
  // GET /customer/:id
  getCustomer: function(req, res, next) {
    users.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: users.product,
      }]
    }).then(function (stores) {
      if (stores.length === 0) {
        res.json('There are no stores in the database');
      }
      res.json(stores);
    });
  },
};
```

I am unable to get the `product` table data. It always shows an error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined.

Why the  `product` table is not fetched in users model? How can I access this product table data by the users model?

Answer (score 0):

Update your **User Controller File** as

```
    const dbConfig = require( '../../../db/models/index');
    let users =require('../../../db/models/user')(dbConfig.sequelizeDB,dbConfig.Sequelize);
    let product=require('../../../db/models/product')(dbConfig.sequelizeDB,dbConfig.Sequelize);
    module.exports = {
      // GET /customer/:id
      getCustomer: function(req, res, next) {
        users.findAll({
          include: [{
            model: product,
          }]
        }).then(function (stores) {
          if (stores.length === 0) {
            res.json('There are no stores in the database');
          }
          res.json(stores);
        });
      },
    };
```

Comment: no this is wrong process. I have solve this issue by myself